# rellenar espacios del "Border-Radius" - DIV

Tags: css, html5, css3

estoy diseñando un pequeño formulario que consta de 3 cuerpos que son "DIV" y tengo esto. Como se puede apreciar en la imagen, al colocar los border radius con CSS, los espacios cogen el color del "BODY".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria que coja el color de los "DIV" de abajo y que quede algo así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

y por si fuese necesario colocar mis css.

```
//SU CONTENEDOR
.divlogin{
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    padding : 0px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    /*height: 500px;*/
    border-radius: 10px;
}

//DIV AZUL
.loginheader{
    background: #00A1EA;
    height: 130px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

//DIV BLANCO
.logincuerpo{
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

//DIV PLOMO
.loginfooter{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background: #B5B6AE;
    height: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

Mi HTML:

```
<div class="divlogin" id="divlogin">
    <div class="loginheader">
        <img src="img/soporteberamar.png" alt="error" class="login_logosoporte">
    </div>
    <div class="logincuerpo">
    </div>
    <div class="loginfooter">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes organizado tu HTML?

Comment: Acabo de editar mi pregunta estimado, ignora los nombres de las clases, así me guío :).
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Tu problema es muy sencillo de resolver, ya publiqué mi respuesta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trata poniendo un color de fondo a tu contenedor `.divlogin`

```
.divlogin{
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

Tu código css final quedaría así:

```
.divlogin{
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    padding : 0px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    /*height: 500px;*/
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.loginheader{
    background: #00A1EA;
    height: 130px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.logincuerpo{
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px #B5B6AE;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px #B5B6AE;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px #B5B6AE;
}
```

Y tu HTML así:

```
<div class="divlogin" id="divlogin">
    <div class="loginheader">
        <img src="img/soporteberamar.png" alt="error" class="login_logosoporte">
    </div>
    <div class="logincuerpo">
    </div>

</div>
```

No necesitabas de un div footer para poder hacer el efecto que quieres, con la propiedad `box-shadow` es suficiente.

Como comentario adicional, también agregaría que si todos tus bordes tendran el mismo radio, no le encuentro sentido darle formato a cada borde, con `border-radius: 10px;` haría el trabajo :)

Comment: tienes razón, no me había dado cuenta que tenia 4 border- radius para las 4 esquinas cuando solo podía tener uno, y con respecto a tu solución, el color de arriba lo ocupa, pero el abajo no, lo ocupa su mismo color, osea el border radius de abajo de pierde en el div Blanco.
Igualmente gracias !!

Comment: @AngelCayhualla No me percaté de esos bordes, lo siento, pero ya actualicé mi respuesta :)

Comment: Fantástico, el `box-shadow` lo hizo todo, genial . Gracias !!

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre que puedes utilizar el selector `::after` de css para crear un fondo encima del contenedor inferior. A continuación lo pones por detrás del contenedor superior con `z-index` y hace el efecto de tapado. De esta manera no tienes que cambiar ni la posición ni el tamaño del segundo contenedor.

Te dejo un ejemplo con dos contenedores;

```css
#superior {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#inferior {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

#inferior::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:-20px;
  left:0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="superior"></div>
<div id="inferior"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué usar pseudelementos?, basta con ponerle un fondo blanco al contenedor...

Comment: Cuando respondí no había código HTML y no lo he camibiado pues es una solución factible, aparte de la que tu has aportado. Saludos

Comment: Voy a probar esta solución, Gracias !!